# Custom page slide transition for PhoneGap App without any UI Frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, css-transitions

I need a custom page slide transition for my new PhoneGap Project, Please help me to how to create a custom page slide transition using html5, css3 and javascript

Thanks advance..

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend [PageSlider](https://github.com/ccoenraets/PageSlider) by Christopher Conraets (an Adobe employee and strong proponent of PhoneGap - check out [this talk](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/05/architecting-a-phonegap-application-video-slides/) by him about good rules for PhoneGap development if you're interested).

I'm using this at the moment. It feels good and is very easy to work with.

Comment: Rory O'Keeffe, i am tried this, but some issues when using android hardware back button

Comment: Hi @Shafi, you can do something like `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);` in your onDeviceReady function where onBackKeyDown() is a function that does what you would like the back button to do, e.g. `function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    logJs('Android back button captured');
    e.preventDefault();
    goBack();
    return false;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Check out this plugin [pagingSlider](http://www.linslin.org/2015/01/13/css-hardware-accelerated-page-transitions/).

#### Features

- slide to pages with touch swipes
- auto switch to pages by clicking menu item
- animated mobile pagebrowser
- integrated touch events with QuoJS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**
shafi plz use
**

```
transform translate3d 3d in css3
```

> to translate the pages left to rigth and rigth to left
>   [example](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-02-slide-flip.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Mobile transitions :
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/transitions/

Comment: Yes Anas, i know jQuery Mobile framework, but i am looking for page transition without any ui framework...

Answer (score -2):

IScroll4 is a good tool for you。 http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4